# Android Volley - Cancel NetworkImageView request in Base Adapter

Tags: android, android-volley

As the title says, I'm using a BaseAdapter to display items in a ListView. Obviously a ListView will reuse views, including TextViews and NetworkImageViews.

Assuming 3 items can be displayed at once, the NetworkImageView will be reused for items at index: 1, 4, 7, ....

Depending on what's being displayed, the NetworkImageView will either:

1. request the image from the Network and display it,
2. display a cached Bitmap,
3. or display a local drawable resource.

Items 2 and 3 work fine, however in Scenario 1, let's say we're displaying item at index 4 from the network, and the user scrolls to item 7 before 4 is loaded and it's a local resource, we display the local resource.  However our network image request may just be finishing now, so we end up displaying an incorrect image.

How can I enforce the proper (expected)behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer from @Snicolas is spot on, but lacks some pointers on how to actually accomplish that. So here goes.

The general idea is to keep track of the ongoing image requests for every row. That way, when you encounter a recycled row, you can cancel the pending request and kick off a new one for the new data relevant to that row.

One straightforward way to accomplish that is to make the `ImageContainer` that you can get back when requesting an image load, part of the adapter's ViewHolder/RowWrapper. If you're not using this pattern yet, you should. Plenty of examples out there, including a good I/O talk.

Once you've added the `ImageContainer` to your holder, make an image request and store the container that you get back. Somewhat like this:

```
ImageListener listener = ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageview, defaultImageResId, errorImageResId);
holder.mImageContainer = ImageLoader.get(url, listener);
```

The next time a recycled row comes in the adapter's `getView()` method, you can get your holder back from it and check wether it has a `ImageContainer` set. One of the following 3 scenarios may apply:

- There is no `ImageContainer`, which means you're good to go to make a new image request.
- There is an `ImageContainer` and the url that it is loading is the same as for the new row data. In this case you don't have to do anything, since it's already loading the image you're after.
- There is an `ImageContainer` but the url that it is loading is different from the new row data. In this case, cancel the request and make a new one for the current row data.

If you like, you can move some of this logic by having your `BaseAdapter` extension implement [`AbsListView.RecyclerListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.RecyclerListener.html) (and set the adapter as recycler listener for the `ListView` or `GridView`). The `onMovedToScrapHeap(View view)` method gets passed in the view that has just been recycled, which means you can cancel any pending image requests in there.

Comment: @Pork's answer is the correct one but this is very useful information for when not using a `NetworkImageView`.  Also good info on using `AbsListView.RecyclerListener`, if someone needs further control of the views. +1

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I only have a doubt, how can you cancel requests made using the method get from the ImageLoader? you can't add a tag to these requests, which is what you need to cancel a request.

Comment: Nevermind, I've seen that the class ImageContainer has its own method to cancel the request which image is intended to hold.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to enforce anything if you use the provided NetworkImageView.

NetworkImageView detects when it has been recycled and cancels the request automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not actually answering the question. In an adapter for something like a ListView, the corresponding view is recycled and therefore it will never detach.

Comment: Can you show me where that happens if you don't mind? The one thing with Volley is that there are no "releases" or version numbers, so it could just be that I'm using an older version.

Comment: When a view is recycled, you have to set the NetworkImageView with a new value in getView of your adapter. At this point, the NetworkImageView will kill off the old request. This happens as part of the recycle process, so the situation that the OP describes will simply never occurs if they use NetworkImageView.

You are correct in stating that NetworkImageView isn't canceling the request upon detaching from the listview, only once it has been recylced does the request stop. I've updated my answer, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know this API but my guess is that you should cancel any pending request before recycling such a view. How you can do that I can't say.

Did you here of alternatives like :

- [picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) ?
- [robospice UI Module](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice/tree/release/extensions/robospice-ui-spicelist-parent) ?